# How to get a substring after first and second white space in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem in oracle ,i.e  I have  a policy number as `'  125896547        0101'`, I need  a substring as `'125896547'`.The first space and the second space after the digits should be removed. I am using the query as

```
 substr(RC_POLICY_NO,1,instr(RC_POLICY_NO,''))
```

which is  not working , please suggest.

Comment: first space and second space? can you please elaborate? Do you mean you want to eliminate the space and the digits that follow the space (0101 in your example)

Comment: Are there two spaces between the policy number? Your requirement is to get the number before space right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with [a regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm), to get the first string of consecutive digits from your value:

```
regexp_substr(RC_POLICY_NO, '\d+')
```

or all characters between the first and second block of spaces:

```
regexp_substr(RC_POLICY_NO, '[^ ]+')
```

Quick demo:

```
with t (RC_POLICY_NO) as (select '  125896547        0101' from dual)
select regexp_substr(RC_POLICY_NO, '\d+'), regexp_substr(RC_POLICY_NO, '[^ ]+')
from t;

REGEXP_SU REGEXP_SU
--------- ---------
125896547 125896547
```

You can so it with normal `substr()`, but you need to search for a spave rather than null as you are currently doing; and to remove the leading spaces you can trim it first:

```
substr(ltrim(RC_POLICY_NO), 1, instr(ltrim(RC_POLICY_NO), ' ') - 1)
```

Demo of that approach:

```
with t (RC_POLICY_NO) as (select '  125896547        0101' from dual)
select substr(ltrim(RC_POLICY_NO), 1, instr(ltrim(RC_POLICY_NO), ' ') - 1)
from t;

SUBSTR(LT
---------
125896547
```

That assumes there will always be a space after the string you want; if you might be starting from a value that doesn't have the two blocks of characters then you'd need to do a bit more work.

if this is something you will do a lot, it might be worth adding a virtual column and/or function-based index so you can search for specific values more easily.

Comment: I am using your query as SELECT RC_PAYMENT_METHOD,RC_POLICY_NO, RC_INSURED FROM D040100 WHERE substr(RC_POLICY_NO, '\d+') ='6306582'; but giving invalid number

Comment: @Mandrek - look again - I used `regexp_substr()`, not `substr()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to select the number before space.

```
SELECT 
     REGEXP_SUBSTR ( RC_POLICY_NO , '[^ ]+' , 1 , 1 ),
FROM DUAL ;
```

The output when you execute the above query is 125896547 for your example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Oracle instance to check this but is it the space at the beginning causing your issue.

Your code is working from the 1st character to the first instance of a space character which is also the first character in the string

Try trimming it first

```
substr(LTRIM((RC_POLICY_NO,1,instr(RC_POLICY_NO,'')),' ')
```